# How can I store certain information into my csv using the tweepy API?

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter, tweepy

I am using the tweepy API and I only want to store certain information into my CSV file. Right now it is storing everything. How can I change my code to only store certain things into my CSV file? I want to store the tweet text, tweet id, username, geo coordinates, hashtags, as well as the time and date of the tweet.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import time

import twitter_credentials


class listener(StreamListener):

  def on_data(self,data):
    try:
      print(data)



      saveTweets = open('SaveTweets.csv', 'a')  #open a csv which we will append to 
      saveTweets.write(data)   #write to csv 
      saveTweets.write('\n') #new lines for new tweet infro 
      saveTweets.close()
      return True
    except BaseException, e:
      print('failed ondata', str(e))
      time.sleep(5)


  def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)


auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.API_KEY, twitter_credentials.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN, twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["plumber"])
```

This is a picture of my CSV file

[image: Data writen]

There is more information that did not fit in the picture but as you can see the CSV contains all the information and I am only looking for certain information.

Comment: you have to create a dictionary and map with your csv column name you have defined and insert it one by one into that csv

Comment: `data` is probably in JSON format containing nested information. Your script will need to convert this into a Python data structure using the Python JSON library, i.e. `import json` and then extract each element you want. This then needs to be written using the Python CSV library `import csv`. Currently you are just writing raw JSON data to a file. Unfortunately, it is not easy to see what the data structure is from a picture.